# need to implement in razor a map control written aspx code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a newbie with asp.net mvc3. I'm working in a project that needs to render a view with a google map control in it, with previous definition of certain parameters for the map location.

I've got access to the code in aspx for the map user control. Can anyone help me to implement this code in razor? or I just create a partial view just for the map?

thanks a lot in advance!

Dani

Answer (score 2):

It would be the best to create separate partial view for map control. Then you can include that view in all pages you need it by calling:

```
@Html.RenderPartial('YourMapPartialViewName', new { ... })
```

Second parameter is used to pass additional variables to partial view if needed.

It is always better to use partial view for controls, because you can easily reuse them on different pages in your project. Make sure you put all the code needed for map control in this partial view.

Hope this helps.